# Block comment issue with Eclipse Mars

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-jdt

I have recently started using eclipse mars and found a very irritating issue. When I comment a multi-line block of code using `ctrl+shft+/`, it comments the block between /* */ but as soon as I save it, it puts a * in front of all the lines in the block. Now when I try to uncomment it using `ctrl+shft+\`, only the start & end /* and */ are removed but the * added to all the lines not. What setting do I need to change in order to remove this auto formatting?

Example:

Comment formatting before save

```
/*This is just an example
of multi-line block comment
in eclipse mars*/
```

Comment formatting after save

```
/*
* This is just an example
* of multi-line block comment
* in eclipse mars
*/
```

Un-comment formatting after save, *** are not removed that were added by eclipse**

```
* This is just an example
* of multi-line block comment
* in eclipse mars
```

Comment: have you changed any thing at Preferences --> java -->Code Style --> Code Template --> patterns of Comments (File / Types/ Fields /Constructor...) ?

Comment: @ArdeshanaMilan, nothing that I remember.

Comment: can you specify which version and what environment for from which update site you downloaded? I tried in mars.1 , it works as normal.

Comment: @ArdeshanaMilan, I downloaded it from eclipse foundation's website for linux. I have switched off formatting for now.

Comment: if you feel its a bug in eclipse platform then please file a bug under eclipse -->  product : Java Development Tools.  with details mentioned in question(How to reproduce).Here is the link https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=JDT.

Comment: @ArdeshanaMilan, it is not a bug and found a solution finally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I used the information posted in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5199277/5036536) which worked as desired.