# Disable format on save in Eclipse Oxygen

Tags: eclipse

I am trying to turn off auto formatting in Eclipse Oxygen 4.7.0 on save.
I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5199255/how-to-disable-auto-formatting-upon-save-in-eclipse/5199277#5199277) solution.
I have all perform action on save disabled.
(Window-Preferences-Java-Editor-Save Actions- unchecked 'Perform the selected actions on save'.
Same for 'Project Specific Settings'.
It this a bug or is there a way to fix this?

edit - pictures from settings. (no project specific settings)
[image: global]
[image: projects]

Comment: Are you sure you looked at both the Project specific settings and the global Preferences setting. There is nothing else that controls formatting on save (for Java).

Comment: Yes I have checked this. Edit the original question to prove it.

Comment: Solved! Thanks for the input. The problem was that I had plugin installed. I uninstalled AnyEdit and CheckStyle.

Comment: @Tor AnyEdit does not format the code, but removes trailing whitespace and replaces tabs<->spaces on save. This can be configured/disabled in _Window > Preferences: General > Editors > AnyEdit Tools_.

Comment: @howlger thank you! My problem was exactly that. Empty lines/tabs were removed. Good tip

Comment: @Tor I added this as answer for others.

Answer (score 2):

If this is not **caused** by the *Save Actions*, then **maybe by a plug-in** that you have installed.

[***AnyEdit Tools***](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/anyedit-tools) is the most popular plug-in which removes trailing whitespace by default. This can be configured/disabled in *Window > Preferences: General > Editors > AnyEdit Tools*.