# Prevent linebreaks with eclipse code formatter

Tags: java, eclipse, formatter

I use the Eclipse formatter with the option on save enabled.

Right now code like this:

```
 int sum = widgets.stream()
                  .filter(b -> b.getColor() == RED)
                  .mapToInt(b -> b.getWeight())
                  .sum();
```

will be formatted to:

```
 int sum = widgets.stream().filter(b -> b.getColor() == RED).mapToInt(b -> b.getWeight())
                  .sum();
```

is there a setting which will do automated linebreak for everything but cascading function calls?

Comment: I think this may be answered here: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5199255/how-to-disable-auto-formatting-upon-save-in-eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5199255/how-to-disable-auto-formatting-upon-save-in-eclipse)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Steps to format cascading function calls:

**1.** Window => Preferences => Java => Code Style => Formatter

**2.** Click Edit.

**3.** Expand Line Wrapping => Wrapping Settings => Function Calls

**4.** Change **Qualified invocations** to *Wrap all elements, except first
    element if not necessary*.

- Additionally, ensure *Force split, even if line shorter than maximum line width* is toggled **on**.

See image below for what it looks like when set correctly:

[image: Qualified Invocation Location]

**5.** Change Profile Name if necessary.

**6.** Apply and close.